# sonar issue in package line "creates and initializes a collection but never reads or gains information from it"

Tags: java, sonarqube

Sonar is telling me there is an issue

```
Class com.xxx.MyClass creates and initializes a collection but never reads or gains information from it
```

Two things to say:

1. We can'f find any collection in that situation and
2. The line sonar marks as incorrect (red underwrting) is the first line of the file, the `package com.xxx`

I've tried the

```
@SuppressWarnings("fb-contrib:WOC_WRITE_ONLY_COLLECTION_FIELD")
```

just above the class declaration line but still receiving the same message.

Any idea as to how to ignore this message or solve this issue?

Many thanks

Comment: If Sonar puts the marker at the top of the file, that must mean it's not getting a line number for where it is occurring, so I think it must be in generated code, perhaps by Lombok or some other annotation processor? I think if you decompile / delombok / `javap -c` the class file you may be able to identify the cause.